# Filled circle in matrix(2D array)

Tags: c++, matrix, geometry

Which algorithm to use to get points of filled circle?

```
int start_X = 30; // center point
int start_Y = 30;

int r = 5;

// current point
int x; 
int y;

if(?==true)
{
map2D[x][y] = 1; // for filled circle points
}
```

Comment: Calculate the length of the line between (x,y) and the center of the circle (cx, cy) and if it's <= r you know it lies within the circle.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Maybe calculate the **square** of the length and compare it with `r * r` will be better.

Comment: What u mean by  points of filled circle??

Comment: Did u mean point is in circle?

Comment: @johnchen902: Not sure I follow, if (a*a)<(b*b) then a<b (as long as both a and b are positive, which they would be).

Comment: if the distance between x,y and center is less than radius, it is inside circle

Comment: @JonathanPotter 1. radius (`r`) must be positive 2. length (`sqrt(...)`) must be positive

Comment: @johnchen902: You can't have a line with negative length.

Comment: @JonathanPotter
Very simple.
It is exactly what i need(for another algorithm).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You get the equation of a circle:

[image]

where a & b are the center point coordinates. All x & y points that satisfy this equation are part of the circle. To see if a certain point (x1, y1) is, check if

```
((x1 - start_X) * (x1 - start_X) + (y1 - start_Y) * (y1 - start_Y)) <= r * r
```

The <= sign is to include the points that lie inside the circle, too. You can safely limit the point ranges in the intervals [start_X - r; startX + r] and [start_Y - r; startY + r].

Answer (score 4):

You can search over a square  region 2`r` by 2`r` with center (`start_X`,`start_Y`):

```
std::vector< std::pair<int> > circlePoints;

for(int i = start_X - r; i <= start_X + r; i++)
{
   for(int j = start_Y - r; j <= start_Y + r; j++)
   {
       if((i-r)*(i-r) + (j-r)*(j-r) <= r*r)
       {
         circlePoints.push_back(std::pair<int>(i,j));
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: this is incorrect. it should be `if((i-start_X)*(i-start_X) + (j-start_Y)*(j-start_Y) <= r*r)` i believe

Comment: The equation shown in this solution is indeed in error. However, I tested Chris' correction in Lua, and that does work.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisChevalier, with your correction it works.

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna go stright to all point in the circle without checking, this is the way.

```
SatY = CenterY;//StartY + R
        for (int i = StartX; i < EndX; i++)
        {
            int StartY = (int)(SatY - Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs((R + i - StartX) * (R - i + StartX))));
            int EndY = (int)(SatY + Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs((R + i - StartX) * (R - i + StartX))));
            for (int j = StartY; j < EndY; j++)
            {
                // Do Job
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete solution in Java. You can easily convert it to C++. Start with an empty matrix predefined with all 0's and fill it with 1's if that the point(x,y) lies inside a circle else fill the outer circle with 9's. (Why 9 - just so that you see circle clearly drawn in the matrix). Below code works fine for the matrix of the odd size. Let me know if anyone has a better solution.

```
  private static void drawCircle(int[][] emptyMatrix, int diameter) {
    int startX = diameter/2;
    int startY = diameter/2;
    int radius = diameter/2;
    drawCircleRecursive(emptyMatrix, diameter, startX, startY, radius, radius);

    System.out.println("Filled matrix: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < emptyMatrix.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < emptyMatrix[0].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(emptyMatrix[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  private static void drawCircleRecursive(int[][] emptyMatrix, int d, int startX, int startY, int x, int y) {

    if(x >= emptyMatrix.length || y >= emptyMatrix[0].length || x < 0 || y < 0 || emptyMatrix[x][y] == 1)
      return;
    else if(emptyMatrix[x][y] == 9)
      return;

    int r = d/2;
    if (((x - startX) * (x - startX) + (y - startY) * (y - startY)) <= (r * r))
      emptyMatrix[x][y] = 1; 
    else 
      emptyMatrix[x][y] = 9;

    drawCircleRecursive(emptyMatrix, d, startX, startY, x+1, y);  // down
    drawCircleRecursive(emptyMatrix, d, startX, startY, x, y+1);  // right
    drawCircleRecursive(emptyMatrix, d, startX, startY, x-1, y);  //up
    drawCircleRecursive(emptyMatrix, d, startX, startY, x, y-1);  //left
    drawCircleRecursive(emptyMatrix, d, startX, startY, x-1, y-1); // diagonal up-left
    drawCircleRecursive(emptyMatrix, d, startX, startY, x+1, y+1); // diagonal right-down
    drawCircleRecursive(emptyMatrix, d, startX, startY, x+1, y-1);  // diagonal left-down
    drawCircleRecursive(emptyMatrix, d, startX, startY, x-1, y+1);  // diagonal right-up


  }
```

Comment: It can be called `int n = 7;
    int[][] emptyMatrix = new int[n][n]; drawCircle(emptyMatrix, n);`