# R: Extract a circle from a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Given a square matrix with sides of length L, how one can extract in R all the values that fall into the largest possible circle able to fill the matrix?

[image]

I found [Filled circle in matrix(2D array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163636/filled-circle-in-matrix2d-array) for C++ but how to test if the position of each cell of the matrix falls into the equation? How to know the X and Y of each cell while using an apply for exemple?

Comment: What is the application? Homework?

Comment: See `?row` and `?col`

Comment: Not really homework. I process huge rasters and want to try if using matrices is more efficient.

Comment: Test the distance to the centre of the square from the centre of each of the cells. Pythagoras can help you. For an 8x8 square matrix the centre is at (4.5, 4.5), the cells are at integers from (1,1) to (8,8) and the circle radius is 4.

Comment: But how do I get the row and col of the cell being processed by the function in apply?

Comment: Create a matrix of cell row/col pairs using expand.grid

Comment: create a B/W bitmap in simplest paint-like editor (either with a black circle or with a radial gradient, if you want Gaussian-like distribution to smooth the edges), load it with `readImage` and take the mask from here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some 8x8 matrix `m`:

```
m = matrix(1:64,8,8)
```

create a data frame of the coordinates:

```
g = expand.grid(1:nrow(m), 1:nrow(m))
```

compute distance-to-centre:

```
g$d2 = sqrt ((g$Var1-4.5)^2 + (g$Var2-4.5)^2)
```

compare with circle radius:

```
g$inside = g$d2<=4
```

you now have a data frame of row, column, distance to centre, and is-it-inside:

```
> head(g)
  Var1 Var2       d2 inside
1    1    1 4.949747  FALSE
2    2    1 4.301163  FALSE
3    3    1 3.807887   TRUE
4    4    1 3.535534   TRUE
5    5    1 3.535534   TRUE
```

Then you can extract from a matrix by a two-column matrix with:

```
m[as.matrix(g[g$inside,c("Var1","Var2")])]
[1]  3  4  5  6 10 11 12 13 14 15 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
[26] 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 50 51 52 53 54 55 59 60
[51] 61 62
```

from your image that should be 64 minus 12 (three in each corner) cells, so the length of 52 in my answer looks correct.

If you are looking for speed then skip the square root and compare with 16, the distance-squared. But you'll probably find a solution in C++ much faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. My main concern is memory rather than speed. I'm already performing this analysis using the velox package but get memory errors while processing the larger rasters. Converting these rasters into matrices and apply your solution is a bit quicker and less demanding in memory. I will certainly test C++ for spatial analysis sooner or later..