# lua: attempt to index a nil value (field '?')

Tags: lua

I'm getting this error in this file:

```lua
-- mid point circle drawing algoritm taken from here:
-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163636/filled-circle-in-matrix2d-array
-- code translated from java

-- initates 2d array
matrix = {}

for i = 1, 2 do
    matrix[i] = {}
end

-- given matrix and diameter populates array
function mCircle(matrix, d)
    local startX = d/2
    local startY = d/2
    local r = d/2
    mCircleRec(matrix, d, startX, startY, r, r)

    --prints matrix
    for i = 1, d do
        for j = 1, d do
            print(matrix[x][y])
        end
    end

end

function mCircleRec(matrix, d, startX, startY, x, y)
    if (x >= d or y >= d or x < 0 or y < 0 or matrix[x][y] == 1)
    then 
        return
    elseif (matrix[x][y] == 9)
    then 
        return
    end

    local r = d/2

    if (((x - startX) * (x - startX) + (y - startY) * (y - startY)) <= (r * r))
    then
        matrix[x][y] = 1
    else
        matrix[x][y] = 9
    end

    mCircleRec(matrix, d, startX, startY, x+1, y);  -- down
    mCircleRec(matrix, d, startX, startY, x, y+1);  -- right
    mCircleRec(matrix, d, startX, startY, x-1, y);  --up
    mCircleRec(matrix, d, startX, startY, x, y-1);  --left
    mCircleRec(matrix, d, startX, startY, x-1, y-1); -- diagonal up-left
    mCircleRec(matrix, d, startX, startY, x+1, y+1); -- diagonal right-down
    mCircleRec(matrix, d, startX, startY, x+1, y-1);  -- diagonal left-down
    mCircleRec(matrix, d, startX, startY, x-1, y+1);  -- diagonal right-up
end

mCircle(matrix, 20)
```

The complete error message:

```sh
lua: circle.lua:27: attempt to index a nil value (field '?')
stack traceback:
        circle.lua:27: in function 'mCircleRec'
        circle.lua:16: in function 'mCircle'
        circle.lua:54: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

This is a simple filled circle algoritm that creates a 2d array and places inside a filled circle, the code was translated from java and the original code is in one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163636/filled-circle-in-matrix2d-array) .

---

I'm new to lua and I looked in every other question about the same error but none of them was relevant.
Thanks in advance for the help

---

edit: typo

---

edit:
While troubleshooting I discovered another error:
I got wrong the 2d array creation and modified it:

```lua
- initates 2d array

local radius = 20
local diameter = radius * 2

-- Create a diameter x diameter array
matrix = {}
for i = 1, diameter do

    matrix[i] = {}

    for j = 1, diameter do
        matrix[i][j] = 0      -- Fill the values here
    end

end
```

Changing this didn't change the error message

Comment: Remove space in `local start Y = d/2`

Comment: The error is in the first line of the body of `mCircleRec`. You might need to find a text editor that shows you line numbers.

Comment: Thanks @EgorSkriptunoff , I fixed the typo but this didn't change the error.

Comment: Sorry @luther the error was a line 27, I wrote that comment directly on the stack overflow editor and chose the wrong line

Comment: @Piglet: If you're referring to the `local start Y` issue, the interpreter doesn't seem to catch the sytax error (version 5.3.3). When I insert `print(start, Y, startY)`, it shows that the variable `Y` is defined.

Comment: @luther because it is not a syntax error. it defines a local nil value `start` and a global `Y` assigned `d/2`   so there is nothing to catch. but there were other errors and not the one he reported when I posted his code so I presume he didn't copy paste the code that causes the index error

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided does not cause the quoted error message.

First you had this

```
local start Y = d/2
```

which you fixed already

Then there is a broken if statement

```
if (x >= d or y >= d or x < 0 or y < 0 or matrix[x][y] == 1)  --the error is in this line (27) apparently
    then
        matrix[x][y] = 1
    then 
        return
    elseif (matrix[x][y] == 0)
    then 
        return
    end
```

where you have two `then`s

Only after fixing these errors you will get to the point where you see the quoted error.

Inside `mCircle` `x` and `y` are nil. So `matrix[x][y]` is not possible.

Comment: Ok I fixed the error, any idea how could I make it work?

Comment: aks a new question then, changing your question even after it was already answered doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: Are you sure? I added the correction on the bottom which is just a minor modification that didn't change the error which is still the same. I don't see how repeating a question that is still basically the same will change the situation. The question remains.

Comment: I already told you that the error is caused by x and y being  nil. what else do you need to know? you cannot `print(matrix[x][y])`  I can't even make sense of the code you added to your question. why do you think renaming matrix to array will stop x and y being nil?

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry turns out I made lots of mistakes.\
1. My edit on the main question was because I was creating the 2D array not the right way and also naming the array array instead of matrix\
2. I cannot do `print(matrix[x][y]` because it was supposed to be ``print(matrix[i][j])`
3. It is now working as intended\
Sorry I wasted your time, I will proceed to write the answer myself and mark this as solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that, when I was trying to print the array i was giving x and y as indexes instead of i and j. 
Also at first I was defining the 2D array the wrong way, like this `matrix = {{}}` which doesn't work.